# HDP 2.6.5 : I create a database in python with pyspark but the database don't appear in hive view 2.0

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive

I have a problem with my database created with pyspark:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession, HiveContext
                                                                                                                                                                        
conf = SparkConf().set("spark.jars.packages","org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.3.2")
                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                        
spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("test") \
        .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/user/maria_dev/output2.json")
                                                                                                                                                                        
#Database on Hive                                                                                                                                                       
spark.sql("create database testdb")

print('Voici le Dataframe : ', df)

df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("testdb.test3")

spark.sql("SHOW DATABASES").show()

df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM testdb.test3")
df.show()
```

I have no errors with this code, but when I go to the ambari interface I don't see my database: there are only "default" and "foodmart". When in the shell with:

```
spark.sql("SHOW DATABASES").show()
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM testdb.test3")
```

I can see my database and its content like this:

```
+---------+
|namespace|                                                                                                                                 +---------+                                                                                                                                 |  default|                                                                                                                                 |   testdb|                                                                                                                                 +---------+
```

What can I do to see my database on hive and to use it on zeppelin.

I try with maria_dev and root. I tried to restart hive.

Answer (score 0):

So you have not set the `.enableHiveSupport()` while creating the `SparkSession`. Currently, the database is getting stored in a default data_warehouse location. Whenever you start the shell it reads from that data_warehoues (the table that you saved). So to save the data into hive you can do the following:

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession, HiveContext
                                                                                                                                                                        
conf = SparkConf().set("spark.jars.packages","org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.3.2")
                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                        
spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("test") \
        .enableHiveSupport() \ # This will use the hive to store the data while using spark sql.
        .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/user/maria_dev/output2.json")
                                                                                                                                                                        
#Database on Hive                                                                                                                                                       
spark.sql("create database testdb")

print('Voici le Dataframe : ', df)

df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("testdb.test3")

spark.sql("SHOW DATABASES").show()

df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM testdb.test3")
df.show()
```